# Comment out page title in Coraline theme/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can someone advise where to comment out the page title in Coraline theme? I've tried different things and it does not work. Here's my page.php

```
    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
                    <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php } else { ?> 


                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 


                <?php } ?>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'coraline' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'coraline' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div> <!-- .entry-content 
            </div> <!-- #post-## -->

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #content-container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it would be this line:

`<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>`

To comment out, replace with:

`<!--<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>-->`

You can also just leave the Title box empty when creating a new page in the admin panel.

Comment: Hi. This is what I tried before and did not work. I also did that in the full-width-page.php which is what I'm using but did not work either. I can't remove it from the title box as it then removes it from the menu...

Comment: If you go into the menu settings you can set the title to whatever you  need from there.